# Web2py: how to style / replace "invalid function" page?

Tags: web2py

How do I provide an alternative or bespoke "invalid function" page when visiting e.g. `mysite.org/no/page`? The default one is a bit basic for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify [`routes_onerror`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Routes-on-error) in the routes.py file to deliver a custom page:

```
routes_onerror = [('myapp/404', '/myapp/static/custom_404.html')]
```

The custom page can also be a dynamic route, such as `/myapp/mycontroller/custom_error`.